# Occurence of a string in a text python

Tags: python, string

There are numerous posts about the occurence of a substring in python, but I can't find anything about the occurrence of a string in a text.

```
testSTR = "Suppose you have a large text and you are trying to find the specific occurences of some words"

#Suppose my search term is a, then I would expect the output of my program to be:
print testSTR.myfunc("a")
>>1
```

Since there is only 1 **concrete** reference to the string "a" in the entire input. `count()` won't do since it counts substrings as well, so the output I get is:

```
print testSTR.count()
>>3
```

Can something like this be done?

Comment: Can you please show your `myfunc()` about what it's doing?

Comment: what do you mean by concrete? There are many references to the string "a" in your input, are you perhaps meaning to search for the _word_ "a"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use collections to do it after splitting the string.

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter(testSTR.split())
```

The output would look like

```
Counter({'you': 2, 'a': 1, 'and': 1, 'words': 1, 'text': 1, 'some': 1, 'the': 1, 'large': 1, 'to': 1, 'Suppose': 1, 'are': 1, 'have': 1, 'of': 1, 'specific': 1, 'trying': 1, 'find': 1, 'occurences': 1})
```

To get the count of a specific substring `a` use,

```
from collections import Counter
res = Counter(testSTR.split())
print res['a']
```

If the count needs to be case-insensitive, convert the substrings using `upper()` or `lower` before counting.

```
res= Counter(i.lower() for i in testSTR.split())
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the most straightforward way is to use regular expressions:

```
import re
testSTR = "Suppose you have a large text and you are trying to find the specific occurences of some words"

print len(re.findall(r"\ba\b", testSTR))
# 1
```

`\ba\b` checks for a "word boundary" both before and after `a`, where a "word boundary" is punctuation, a space, or the beginning or end of the whole string. This is more useful than just splitting on whitespace, unless that's what you want of course...

```
import re
str2 = "a large text a, a. a"

print len(re.findall(r"\ba\b", str2))
# 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about punctuation, you should try this:

```
words = testSTR.split().map(lambda s: s.strip(".!?:;,\"'"))
print "a" in words
```

Comment: I'm not concerned about punctuation, I just want to find the number of **a** in the entire code.